# How can I make bash cut and paste to the X selection?

Tags: bash, xorg

In bash under an xterm, how can I get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> to cut and paste to the X selection?

Comment: In Ubuntu cut is Ctrl-x or Shift-Del, copy is Ctrl-c or Ctrl-Del and paste is Ctrl-v or Shift-Ins. These work happily between most windows, including `term` and `xterm`. The only thing that doesn't work in `xterm` is right-clicking for cut/copy/paste.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash: it's all about your terminal.

Comment: @glennjackman: The `Ctrl+K` and `Ctrl+Y` shortcuts are, in fact, part of bash.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you cannot. Bash doesn't *have* such a feature; it won't talk X11 unless its developers take the time to implement it. (And then, the clipboard would be much more suitable than the primary selection...)

If you want to take a shot, start at `lib/readline/kill.c`; it would be useful as readline is used by several dozen other programs as well.

Otherwise, you will have to use the copy/paste features of your terminal instead.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what you are asking for, but you can use `xsel` to put some contents into the clipboard from the command line. For example:

```
echo "Hello world" | xsel -i
```